# User deleting row in datagridview

Tags: c#, events, datagridview

I'd like to use the UserDeletingRow event to ask the user if he's sure he wants to delete selected row in the dgv. The problem is I don't know how to use this event. Plus I'd like to get informations about the selected row so that I can execute a SQL request to delete the matching row in a SQL Compact database.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you looked at [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.userdeletingrow.aspx)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    private void dataGridView1_UserDeletingRow(object sender, DataGridViewRowCancelEventArgs e)
            {
              if (user don't want to remove the selected row from grid)
                e.Cancel = true; 
            }
```

For update database records get required cell value
for example

Get Record id 
`object val = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells["IdColumns"].Value;`

Comment: Thank you. I've done that but I don't know why the function is never called. I think I have to modify the designer but I don't know how

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your main script:

```
private void DgvResults_UserDeletingRow(object sender, DataGridViewRowCancelEventArgs e)
{
    var result = MessageBox.Show("text", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
    if (result == DialogResult.No)
    {
        e.Cancel = true
    }
}
```

And then add this to the appropriate place in the designer file:

```
this.DgvResults.UserDeletingRow += new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRowCancelEventHandler(this.DgvResults_UserDeletingRow);
```